# How can I do something when I successfully liked an item in facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

how can I do something when I successfully liked an item in  facebook?

I want to run my defined function after facebook's like event (in js), how can i do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe events for these functions.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/